# Non standard sorting and navigation using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, navigation

I am trying to sort the information given to me by the API of an engineering journal. I have extracted the following information into a table:

```
ID                 (integer),
Journal Entry Name (Text),
Description        (Text),
Page Length        (integer),
Has Media          (boolean)
```

Each "Journal Entry" has only one ID associated with it. Each ID also has other characteristics that are not returned by the API but that I want to use to sort. They are:

- Category (Things like Econ, Math, Biology. Each ID can have more than one category)
- Boolean values (Things like requiring special subscriptions)

I have created a second table in the following format:

```
ID       (integer),
Category (text),
Boolean1 (bool),
Boolean2 (bool),
Boolean3 (bool)
```

Since each ID can have more than one category, when this occurs another row is added to this table. The idea being that any given row only has one ID and one category in it.

What I want to do is this:

- Be able to find the top ten categories when it comes to

  - Highest Journal Entry (ID) count
  - Highest Total Page Length
  - Highest Journal Entry count where the "Has Media" boolean is true
- Create a means of navigating like "pagination" where each page shows the nth results of the aforementioned top ten.

  - So if I chose to Highest Journal Entry count method, the first page would be show IDs, Names, and Descriptions of all the Journal entries in the category with the highest count.

My plan has been to create a new table where the numbers one through ten are in the first column, and then populate the second column with the top ten categories. Then I can use a process similar to pagination in which the nth page only shows the values with the corresponding category from the original value. However I can't seem to be able to make this top ten list/matrix, nor do I know if it there is a better way.

Unfortunately I am not a MySQL or PHP coder by trade, and have only gotten this far by lots and lots of googling. I have been completely unable to find any guides for a navigation method like the one I want. And since I don't know the proper terminology, I am just trying random google searches at this point.

Is this the best way to go about it? Or would it be better to create a third table of some sort? Is there perhaps an easier way to do this with something that can use the PHP and MySQL code I already wrote?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear about what you're trying to do, but you might want a bridge or 'junction' table if you have a many to many relationship. [For more info click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand what you're going for here, but my best guess is that you probably want to combine your two initial tables and have category be a set rather than an individual term so you can have a single entry per unique ID.

Then you'd just need to write calls for each of your top ten finds as needed.  Since each id can have an unknown number of categories I would start with a limit of 10 and then process the returns starting with the top match, grab its categories, if there are more than 10 grab the first 10, if there are less than 10 grab what there are, update the amount you're looking for (if there were 4 then you're now looking for 6), and move on to the next best match.

Maybe something like this:

```
categories = null;
$delimeter = ',';
$count = 1;
$top10 = array();

$result = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY page_length DESC
LIMIT 10");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)  && $count <=10)
  {
  $categories = $row['categories'];
  $id = $row['id'];
  $splitcontents = explode($delimeter, $catagories);
  foreach($splitcontents as $category){
     if (!in_array($catagory,$top10)){
        $top10[$count] = array(
            'category'=>$category,
            'journal_id'=>$id
        );
        $count++;
      }
  }
}
```